# failed to get geolocation lat and lng values

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

First I tried to get the lat and lng values in php:

```html
<?php

// set up an array that contains postcodes and the lat and lng data 
$engineer_on_site_jobs=array();

$record_id = 872743;
$post_code = 'PO12 1QB';
prepare_postcode($post_code);
$on_site_time = "12:49:29";
$location = get_lat_and_lng_by_postcode($post_code);
$test_val = 111;
$engineer_on_site_jobs[] = array('record_id'=>$record_id, 'location'=>$location, 'on_site_time'=>$on_site_time, 'postcode'=>$post_code, 'test_val'=>$test_val);    

$record_id = 873752;
$post_code = 'PO9 3DX';
prepare_postcode($post_code);
$on_site_time = "10:43:22";
$location = get_lat_and_lng_by_postcode($post_code);
$test_val = 222;
$engineer_on_site_jobs[] = array('record_id'=>$record_id, 'location'=>$location, 'on_site_time'=>$on_site_time, 'postcode'=>$post_code, 'test_val'=>$test_val);    

echo "<pre>";
print_r($engineer_on_site_jobs);
echo "<pre>";


// local functions /////////////////////

/* 
 * prepare the postcode: remove space 
 * @param  $postcode  
 */
function prepare_postcode(&$post_code){
    $post_code_pieces=explode(' ', $post_code);
    $post_code="$post_code_pieces[0]"."$post_code_pieces[1]";    
}


/* 
 * get loction lat and lng by postcode
 * @param  $postcode  
 * @return array &location[lat, lng]
 */ 
function get_lat_and_lng_by_postcode($postcode){
    $loc=array();
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode";
    //$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&key=browser_key_string_goes_in_here";  
    //$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&key=server_key_string_goes_in_here";  
    //$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&key=browser_key_string_goes_in_here";  
    //$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$postcode&key=server_key_string_goes_in_here";  
        
    $json_data = @file_get_contents($url);    
    $my_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    $location=$my_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];
    $loc['lat']= $location['lat'];
    $loc['lng']= $location['lng'];

    return $loc;
} 

?>
```

I have tried to called the API with or without a key; a browser key or a server key; use http or https, but, these all failed to get the lat and lng (the test URL http://10.211.226.100/mobile/test_location2.php).  However, with the same code, I can have the lat and lng when the file is in another server without any key (the test URL http://10.64.110.68/mobile/test_location2.php).  Why and how can I make it work in 10.211.226.100 ?

Secondly, while failed to get the lat and lng in php, I tried to get them in javascript.

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
   
<script>
function initialize() {
     var engineer_on_site_jobs = <?php echo json_encode($engineer_on_site_jobs);?>;       
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
      
     $(engineer_on_site_jobs).each(function(i, val){

        var postcode = val.postcode;

        geocoder.geocode({'address': postcode}, function(results, status) {
              
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {            

                    console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lng()); 

                    val.location['lat'] =   results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    val.location['lng']  =   results[0].geometry.location.lng();           
 
                    val['test_val']= 444;
                    
                    engineer_on_site_jobs[i] = val;

                } 
         });  
                             
     });
           
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs);
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]);
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['test_val']);
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['location']);
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0].location['lat']); 
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['location']['lat']);   
       console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0].location.lat);   
          

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   
</script>
```

I can see that I have got the lat and lng as the values can be logged in the console when within the geocode function. However, I have lost them outside the function.

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs) output as expected

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]) output as expected

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['test_val']) output 111 instaed of the ecpected 444

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['location']) output  Object {lat: null, lng: null}

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0].location['lat']) output null instaed of an ecpected lat value

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0]['location']['lat'])  output null instaed of an ecpected lat value

console.log(engineer_on_site_jobs[0].location.lat)  output null instaed of an ecpected lat value

Does this related to execution timing/order? How can I set the lat and lng values inside the geocode function and use them outsite the function?

Comment: looks like a subnet issue. Can you ping the desired ip across the lan?

Comment: ping 10.211.226.100 in windows command:

Comment: This was the outcome from command line, I don't understand it, does it tell you anything?

C:\windows\system32>ping 10.211.226.100

Pinging 10.211.226.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.211.226.100: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=122
Reply from 10.211.226.100: bytes=32 time=41ms TTL=122
Reply from 10.211.226.100: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=122
Reply from 10.211.226.100: bytes=32 time=59ms TTL=122

Ping statistics for 10.211.226.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 41ms, Maximum = 59ms, Average = 50ms